# Поиск постов и товаров одновременно

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, search

Как сделать поиск по товарам и постам блога одновременно по одному запросу и c одного поиска

Вот код

```
<form class="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="/">
                <input placeholder="Search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" class="1" />
                <button class="search_btn"><p>Search</p>
                </button>
            </form>
```

Comment: это форма а ваша попытка решить вопрос?

Comment: По-умолчанию стандартный поиск и так должен работать и для товаров в том числе, если что, в случае продукта поиск работает по Product Title, Description или Short Description.

Comment: У многих такая проблема и она решаема, оставить либо результаты поиска по вордпресу или по вукомерсу,а мне нужно одновременно вывести результаты поиска публикаций из вукомерс и вордпреса

Comment: Вы так написали как-будто это я вопрос задал)) Проверил только что на последнем WooCommerce сайте который делал. Поиск работает одновременно по постам и продуктам.

Comment: Прямая цитата со страницы поддержки WooCommerce: "WooCommerce uses the default WordPress search functionality and that would return all content which has any instances of the searched for keywords (In your case IATA) within the Product Title, Description or Short Description." [Ссылка](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/default-product-search/)

Comment: Ты был прав, проблема была в функции которая исключала страницы сайта из поиска, убрав ее все начало искаться. Но теперь как убрать страницы из поиска не убирая с ними товары? :D

Comment: @Zonn а как Вы убирали страницы оттуда?

Comment: Вариантов перепробовал много, вот один из них if ( !is_admin() ) {
    function wpschool_search_filter($query) {
        if ( $query->is_search ) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','wpschool_search_filter' );
}

Comment: Ну логично что поиск работает только по постам, если в `$query->set()` указаны только посты) Если хотите оставить эту же функцию, то можете модифицировать `$query->set('post_type', ['post', 'product']);`. Но имейте ввиду что поиск будет работать только по постам и продуктам, все остальные пост тайпы в пролете. Есть и другой вариант, можно посмотреть [здесь](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5453/how-do-i-remove-pages-from-search)

Comment: @АлександрСычёв я там кавычку не закрыл

Comment: Да я уже понял поэтому удалил сообщение, все заработало) Дело было в этих скобках кашмааар